# Getting {"error": {"message": "7/No match"}} from @react-native-community/voice

Tags: javascript, react-native, voice-recognition, voice

I am working on voice to text conversion project in there I have used @react-native-community/voice library to recognize the voice. After speech start it returning {"error": {"message": "7/No match"}} error

```js
    useEffect(() => {
      const onSpeechStart = (e) => {
        console.log("onSpeechStart")
        setStarted('√')
      };
      const onSpeechEnd = () => {
        console.log('onSpeechEnd');
        setStarted(null);
        setEnd('True');
      };
      const onSpeechError = (e) => {
        console.log('onSpeechError: ', e);
        setError(JSON.stringify(e.error));
      };
      const onSpeechResults = (e) => {
        console.log('onSpeechResults: ', e);
        setResults(e.value)
      };
      const onSpeechPartialResults = (e) => {
      console.log("onSpeechPartialResults", e)
        setPartialResults(e.value)
      };
      const onSpeechVolumeChanged = (e) => {
        console.log("onSpeechVolumeChanged", e)
        setPitch(e.value)
      };

      Voice.onSpeechStart = onSpeechStart;
      Voice.onSpeechEnd = onSpeechEnd;
      Voice.onSpeechError = onSpeechError;
      Voice.onSpeechResults = onSpeechResults;
      Voice.onSpeechPartialResults = onSpeechPartialResults;
      Voice.onSpeechVolumeChanged = onSpeechVolumeChanged;
      return () => {
        Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);
        };
    }, []);

const startSpeechRecognizing = async () => {
  console.log("startSpeechRecognizing");
  setPitch('')
  setError('')
  setStarted('')
  setResults([])
  setPartialResults([])
  setEnd('')
  try {
      await Voice.start('en-US', {
        RECOGNIZER_ENGINE: 'services',
        EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS: true,
      });
      } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
};
const stopSpeechRecognizing = async () => {
  console.log("stopSpeechRecognizing");
  try {
    await Voice.stop();
    setStarted(null);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGHlk.png)

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

try to add
await Voice.start('es_US', {
RECOGNIZER_ENGINE: 'GOOGLE',
EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS: true,
});

if you are testing on emulater be sure to have checked the "Virtual microphone uses hosta audio input" option, in Microphone options from the android emulator

Answer (score 0):

be sure to have checked the "Virtual microphone uses hosta audio input" option, in Microphone options from the android emulator